# Get Error: jinja2.exception.TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'basename'

Tags: python, filter, jinja2

I get this type of error while creating template file.
I have simple use this type of syntax:

```
{{ "hello\how\are" | basename}}
```

Please help me solve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

From what I see in Jinja2 official documentation there is no `basename` filter. 
See [Jinja2 - List of Builtin Filters](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#builtin-filters).

EDIT:
You can write yor own `basename` filter, for example:

```
def basename(text):
    return text.split('\\')[-1]

app.add_template_filter(basename)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error in a stand-alone program that uses Jinja2. In my case I didn't have an app, so I couldn't use app.add_template_filter. I had an Environment instance which has a filters dict. I added to that dict and the filtering went fine. If 'e' is the environment, I did something like this:

```py
e.filters['basename'] = basename
```

Assuming a basename function in the previous answer. With an app, app.jinja_env exposes the environment, so that becomes:

```py
app.jinja_env.filters['basename'] = basename
```